# Align a rating bar to right

Tags: android, listview, alignment

I'm trying to add a Ratingbar to a listview-row that cotains an image and text. My problem is that when I add the ratingbar I can't get it to align to right. It either fill the available area or get align to the left.

My list-row is defined like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView  
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="64px"
    android:layout_height="64px"
    android:paddingLeft="3px"
    ></ImageView>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/drinkName" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25px">
    </TextView>
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall">
    </RatingBar>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance
Roland

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three small changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView  
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="64px"
    android:layout_height="64px"
    android:paddingLeft="3px"
    ></ImageView>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/drinkName" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="25px">
    </TextView>
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall">
    </RatingBar>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a RelativeLayout... e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView  
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="64px"
    android:layout_height="64px"
    android:paddingLeft="3px"
></ImageView>
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/drinkName" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="25px">
</TextView>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RatingBar android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/rating" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></RatingBar>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `gravity`-attribute? Also, you shouldn't use pixel-values. This will make your layout look bad on devices with an other screen-resolution.